# Service Bus in Azure App Services

Tags: azure

I'm planning to use Web Apps feature of Azure App Service and separate the front-end app from one for back-office app. Can I use Service Bus in Azure App Service?

Or Is that something not required.I'm just implementing this design:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/architecture/medium-umbraco-web-app/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Azure Service Bus in Azure App Service.

Comment: Thanks. I got the info also here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/